# Write layer style .qml as predefined within a gpkg using R

Tags: r, qgis-3, qml, geopackage

I have this code to export a layer (Pbm) to a gpkg called "Atlas":

```
writeOGR(Pbm, paste0(normalizePath(OutputFolder),'\\', "Atlas.gpkg"),"Atlas",
             driver="GPKG", encoding = "UTF-8", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

In other hand I have a .qml file with the QGIS style I like and which I want to save within the .gpkg. Does it exist the possibility to write this style within the .gpkg directly from R ?

PD: I already know that copying the .qml file with the same name as the .gpkg layer will add that style directly when loading into QGIS. The issue here is that I don't want that extra file out of the .gpkg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

A GeoPackage is a special kind of SQLite database, and when QGIS saves QML data with a geopackage layer it saves the text and metadata of the QML in a table called `layer_styles`.

The table has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "layer_styles" 
   ( "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
     "f_table_catalog" TEXT(256),
     "f_table_schema" TEXT(256),
     "f_table_name" TEXT(256),
     "f_geometry_column" TEXT(256), 
     "styleName" TEXT(30),
     "styleQML" TEXT,
     "styleSLD" TEXT,
     "useAsDefault" BOOLEAN,
     "description" TEXT,
     "owner" TEXT(30), 
     "ui" TEXT(30),
     "update_time" DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ','now')));
```

You can create a new row in the table using R's database functions - you need to figure out the value of each of those fields and then add or update the row corresponding to the geopackage spatial layer it refers to.

The `styleQML` and `styleSLD` fields contain the XML text of the QML and SLD.

So yes it looks possible and given all the field data would only take a line or five of R database code to open the DB, write the row, and close the connection. There may be some pitfalls I'm missing though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but seems quite challenging. I'll keep saving the .qml next to the .gpkg until I have some time to dig into this structure.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Spacedman I manage to do so by :

-in Qgis(3.2) save your style in database (Geopackage) and export as .gpkg

in R :

```
#I save my style layer as an object
    mystyle <- sf::st_read("file.gpkg", layer = "layer_styles")



#In this object rename the $f_table_name
#Give it the same name as your data layer mine is "pts"
    mystyle$f_table_name <- as.facort("pts")  



sf::st_write(obj = sf::st_as_sf(myData, coords = c("X","Y")), dsn = "myData.gpkg", layer = "pts",  append = TRUE, delete_layer = TRUE)
sf::st_write(mystyle, "myData.gpkg", "layer_styles", append = TRUE)
```

your .gpkg should display your style (at least it worked for me on Qfield)